# How to automate react-select with Playwright

Tags: react-select, playwright

I'm using react-select in my application for implementing CSS styleable dropdowns. Also, I'm using Playwright for automatic testing want to be able to select an option from one of these dropdowns using Playwright. How to?

Comment: Have you tried react selectors in playwright https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#react-selectors ?

Comment: Read about briefly. Would they help here?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the id for both the react-select as well as the input field that react-select supports that allows you to search for an option by text.
For instance I did the following:

```
<Select id={"myReactSelectId"} inputId={"myReactSelectInputId"} options={options} autofocus={true}/>
```

Then with Playwright you can use:

```
const selectOption = async (page: Page, optionText: string) => {
   
   await expect(page.locator("input[id='myReactSelectInputId']")).toBeFocused(); 
   await page.locator("input[id='myReactSelectInputId']").fill(optionText);
   await this.page.keyboard.down("Tab");
}
```

And voila your react-select has now updated to the desired option.

Note: I am using react-select 5.7.3

Answer (score 2):

By trial and error, I came up with this.

```
import { Page, ElementHandle } from "@playwright/test"

export default async function reactSelect(page: Page, instanceId: string, optionText: string) {
  const innerDetailWithKnownId = await page.waitForSelector(`#react-select-${id}-live-region`)
  const select = await parentElement(innerDetailWithKnownId)
  await select!.click()
  const option = await page.waitForSelector(`#react-select-${instanceId}-listbox div:text('${optionText}')`)
  await option.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()
  await option.click()
}

function parentElement(element: ElementHandle<any>) {
  return element.$("xpath=..")
}
```

Here `instanceId` should match the value you used as `instanceId` for the actual react-select in your JSX code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I come up with using `"react-select": "5.4.0"`.

Note that you need to place an id `my_react_select` on your select for this to work

```
const selectOption = async (page: Page, optionText: string) => {
  await page.locator('#my_react_select').click()
  await page.locator(`.react-select__option:text("${optionText}")`).click()
}
```